# SQLAlchemy - Compile Index Differently Depending on Dialect

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy class like so:

```
class TableName(Base):
    __table_args__ = ( 
         Index('index_name', 'column_name'), 
    )
```

I want the name of the index to compile differently depending on the dialect, because as far as I understand it, MySQL can compile indexes with the same name as long as they are in different tables, whereas Sqlite requires every index to have a unique name. We have some tables that use the same index name for mysql, and I want it to compile to sqlite for testing. Is this possible or am I confused for some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to compile the `CreateIndex` function, and use the index and table names that were passed in to create a unique index name:

```
@compiles(CreateIndex, "sqlite")
def compile_index(element, compiler, **kw):
    index_name = element.element.name
    table_name = element.element.table.name 
    column_name = element.element.expressions[0].name
    unique_index_name = f"{table_name} {index_name}"
    return "CREATE INDEX \"%s\" ON %s (\"%s\")" % (unique_index_name, table_name, column_name)
```